# DataTables menu for select items to show per page doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datatables

On my DataTable the box where you can select how many items per page you want to show doesn't work. It is showing me this:
`[[5,10],[5,10]]` instead to show me only the numbers.
I tried to understand what caused this issue but without any success.

If I click on the menu one of the options I have this error also: `Showing NaN to NaN of 2 entries`

I'm using this in my Rails 4 app.

this is my js:

```
var dtMainDataTable;            // Reference to main table
var dtSecondaryDataTable;   // Reference to secondary table
var dtTertiaryDataTable;    // Reference to tertiary table
var dtMainOrder;          // Main table ordering

/*
* Create tables on document ready
*/
$(document).ready( function() {

  // Set the order of the main table and update if overridden by page.
  dtMainOrder = [0, 'asc'];
  if (typeof dtMainOrderUpdate !== 'undefined') {
    dtMainOrder = dtMainOrderUpdate;
  }

  dtMainDataTable = $('#main').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [],
    "pageLength": pageLength,
    "lengthMenu": pageSettings,
    "order": dtMainOrder,
    responsive: true
  });

  dtSecondaryDataTable = $('#secondary').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [],
    "pageLength": pageLength,
    "lengthMenu": pageSettings,
    responsive: true
  });       

  dtTertiaryDataTable = $('#tertiary').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [],
    "pageLength": pageLength,
    "lengthMenu": pageSettings,
    responsive: true
    });

});

/**
 * Show all items in the main table. 
 * Really only for testing purposes.
 *
 * @return [Null] 
 */
function dtMainTableAll() {
  dtMainDataTable.page.len(-1).draw();
}
```

Comment: You need to use paginate:true and paginatetype : full_numbers properties

Comment: I have to include those in a view where I'm using the tables? @sridharreddy

Comment: I added those I have still same problem

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my own question and hope will be useful for others.
I had this in my code: `var pageLength = '#{current_user.table_rows}';`
I dleeted the '' and started working again 
So the result working for me is:
`var pageLength = #{current_user.table_rows};`